# WPS-Office equation editor

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, fonts

I have recently installed WPS-office on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a few problems. The first problem is that when I start any of the WPS-office programs it gives me a error saying that "Some formula symbols might not be displayed correctly due to missing fonts Symbol, Wingdings, Wingdings 2, Wingdings 3, MT Extra." I tried to download the fonts and install them but it didn't work. How do I solve this?

> When I tried to install the fonts, I first downloaded the .deb file from the WPS site, thereafter I ran and tried to install it using Software Center.

My second issue is how do I get equation editor similar to the one in MS Office in WPS-Office or in Ubuntu in general, is this even possible?
Your help will be appreciated. Thankd

Comment: How did you do when trying to install those fonts? Please answer by editing your question.

Comment: Still not good enough explanation. Did you successfully install the package, or did you get some error message?

Comment: The solution from this link helped me : [https://schroeffu.ch/2015/08/wps-office-linux-fehlerbehebung-some-formula-symbols-missing/](https://schroeffu.ch/2015/08/wps-office-linux-fehlerbehebung-some-formula-symbols-missing/)

Comment: Libreoffice has an equation editor (Math) and also has very sane replacement fonts when exporting to MS formats.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For the first issue you need a set of *fonts* for WPS and this should be dropped into the `/usr/share/fonts` folder for system wide access.

Now I have created a **git repo** with these fonts download it from [here](https://github.com/udoyen/wps-fonts) and add it like this:

1. download fonts from [here](https://github.com/udoyen/wps-fonts)
2. create a folder `sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/kingsoft`
3. copy the contents of that download to folder in (2)
4. run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/share/fonts/kingsoft`
5. run `sudo chmod -R o+rw,g+rw /usr/share/fonts/kingsoft` or leave as is if it has `read and write permissions` for owner (you)
6. run `sudo fc-cache -vfs`

For the second issue. You could try this qalculate:

Install: `sudo apt-get install qalculate`

Qalculator resource: https://www.maketecheasier.com/qalculate-powerful-calculator-for-linux/

Comment: Thanks, Qalcalculator is not what I'm looking for exactly though

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Oh... You freed me from this annoying window :D! Thanks)

Answer (score 10):

I just downloaded the fonts and copy them into /usr/share/fonts/wps-office/

It worked for me!

The steps were:

1. Download the fonts as a zip file: https://github.com/udoyen/wps-fonts
2. Unzip the file wps-fonts-master.zip
3. Move the .ttf files to /usr/share/fonts/wps-office/ (`sudo mv ~/Downloads/wps-fonts-master/* /usr/share/fonts/wps-office/`)
4. Restart WPS Office (If it's running)

Answer (score 3):

Following the steps that is in [WPS Office Equation](https://github.com/iamdh4/ttf-wps-fonts.git) repository on Github.

1. Create and access a temporal directory.

   ```
   $ mkdir tmp
   $ cd tmp
   ```
2. Clone the Git repository.

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/iamdh4/ttf-wps-fonts.git
   ```
3. Enter the directory cloned

   ```
   $ cd ttf-wps-fonts
   ```
4. Run the install script

   ```
   $ sudo bash install.sh
   ```
5. Delete the temporal directory

   ```
   $ rm -rf /tmp/ttf-wps-fonts
   ```

I tried it in WPS 10.1.0.5707 on Linux Mint 19 (based on Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 1):

Simply download the fonts in the above answer. The install them using the "Font Manager". You can download it in the software center.

Answer (score 1):

**WPS Office 2019 still does not have an equation editor
does not have the tool as it does in windows**

On Windows in WPS Office 2019 are an Equation Editor Software executable .exe  inside this path:

C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Kingsoft\WPS Office\11.2.0.9906\office6\mui\default\resource\ksee

[image: ksee path]

**Note:** You need enable [view hidden files and folders in windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/) to find that path.

there is the next folder and files:

Fonts

ee3.dsc

EqnEdit.exe

Equation Editor.chm

**Note:** You can open the Windows help file on Linux with: xchm or kchmviewer

In the next picture on Linux I have that folder from WPS Office Windows Version with the executable:

EqnEdit.exe

[image: working Linux with wine]

**Note:** You can obtain that on Windows if you have installed WPS Office. Search in that path.

This software where made for:

http://www.dessci.com

**Note:** I do not know if in the future they ask that company to make a version for Linux

You can execute this on Linux with wine but the formula generated is not possible to insert to WPS Writer and this tool not have any way to export in file the content code formula language to view the code. But there is a way to enter that on WPS Office Linux version with code:

**Enter Fraction and Radical Number in WPS Office Writer enabling Equation Field Code**

Acording to this tutorial: http://help.wps.com/articles/how-to-enter-fraction-and-radical-number-in-writer to enable **Toggle Field Codes** you need to use the shortcut:

Ctrl+F9

now the following appears:

[image: Ctrl + 9]

then in the generated field enter (or paste but wihout format):

eq \f(3,4)

Next, click the right mouse button and choose "Toggle Field Codes" from context menu:

[image: Toggle Field Codes]

now see a fraction:

[image: Fraction]

And in that web page said the next example:

[image: help.wps.com example]

to do that enter:

eq \r(3,2)

with right clic:

[image: right clic]

and edit:

[image: edit to write: eq \r(3,2)]

and appear:

[[image: Appear eq \r(3,2)]

I go to enter this in the same place:

eq \f(3,4 ) eq \r(3,2)

[image: add other formula]

and appear repeated "eq":

[image: appear repeat eq]

for this reason delete this second word:

eq \f(3,4 ) \r(3,2)

[image: then yes]

and now ok:

[image: ok]

Now I do other example:

eq × = \f(13 × 7,201 ÷ 6 ) ÷ \r(4, 2 ÷ 3)

[image: Formula 4]

And Togle Field Codes:

[image: Formula 5]

To do that I insert × and ÷ symbols with that tool in WPS Office:

[image: Symbol Tool]

**¿The rest of the codes?**

I do not know the language in which these codes are written, I have tried to search the Web for a manual to be able to write the formulas in code but I cannot find anywhere. At the moment what I am going to do is write to the developers because there on that page it says that they can be written:

[image: Writing to developers]

If you know the codes for WPS Office 2019 help

Answer (score 0):

2021 update : WPS offece Has a powerful equation editor ( Chemical and Mathimatical ) on ubuntu

> **INSERT > EQUATION > INSERT NEW EQUATION**
>
> [image]