# WPS doesn't start

Tags: 16.04, wps-office

I have recently started using Ubuntu and wanted to try WPS as an alternative to LibreOffice, so I downloaded it and installed it, no problems. Trouble is, when I try to run it (to do so, I click on the icon in the search instrument), the icon on the sidebar appears for a dozen of seconds, then disappears. No windows appear at any point, not even error windows. I don't know how to work with a terminal on my own, I understand maybe 10% of what's written in a terminal command, every time I use the terminal I copy commands from online. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

### Summing it up:

There is some incompatibility that can be overcome by adding `-style gtk` at the end of the `Exec` line in the desktop launcher file.

Example with `kate` text editor:

```
kate /usr/share/applications/wps-office-wps.desktop`
```

Change the line

```
Exec=/usr/bin/wps %f
```

to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/wps %f -style-gtk
```

---

I was also experiencing this problem.  I found the below a Youtube video which uses a different package installer.  I tried this after I had already tried to install it as you normally would.  It would not work for me and I still cannot use WPS.

This may work for you or someone else:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTj2jasYLQQ

Other videos are pretty much stock standard install.  Not sure why it does not install.

Edit:

I use KDE neon and tried further digging into google I came across this:
http://technologyinfinite.blogspot.ru/2017/07/how-to-install-and-open-wps-office-in.html

I am now successfully able to launch and use WPS.

When you are then able to successfully open the application you will be prompted for a font issue, follow the below link to resolve it:
[WPS-Office equation editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861588/wps-office-equation-editor)

Comment: Some wise guy had downvoted this to  -1 while it is a perfectly working answer: although pasting links is not the way to go,  a comment and an edit are preferable to dumb (I mean mute) downvoting.

Comment: Confirmed in Kubuntu  18.04

Answer (score 0):

This is Ubuntu-Studio 22.04 with plasma KDE: same problem found

wps only start GUI when fired with `sudo` &
this is due to a permission issue in the `.deb` package installer

1. Get the rpm package from official site
2. install alien:

   - `sudo apt install alien`
3. Convert downloaded .rpm to .deb:

   - `sudo alien -dc --fixperms wps-office-XX.X.X.XXXX.XA-X._arc_.rpm`
4. install converted .deb as you normally do (I used QApt installer)

> I found this solution here
>
> https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/wps-office-only-runs-as-root-in-lubuntu-18-04/893/24
>
> Hi!
>
> I tested the version 11.1.0.9505 and you can install using RPM package
> 2. First enable the universe repository and install alien.
>
> `sudo apt install alien`
>
> `sudo alien wps-office-11.1.0.9505.XA-1.x86_64.rpm`
>
> The package wps-office-11.1.0.9505.XA-1.x86_64.deb will be builded and you can install with dpkg or APT.
>
> `sudo apt install ./wps-office-11.1.0.9505.XA-1.x86_64.deb`
> Installing this way you can run without superuser.
>
> UPDATE: Now this just work adding parameters:
>
> `sudo alien -dc --fixperms wps-office.rpm`